# how to reference global variable from C that was defined in .asm file in visual studio

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

I have a .asm file that defines variable `foo`

file.asm:

```
.data
foo DWORD 0

.code
{ ... }
```

I want to reference `foo` outside of file.asm in main.c , This what i have tried:

main.c

```
extern int foo;

int main()
{
    foo++;
}
```

However this causes a linker error: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol `foo` , how can i reference it from main.c ?

UPDATE:

I have also tried using the PUBLIC directive:

file.asm:

```
.data
PUBLIC foo
foo DWORD 0
```

This causes same linker error LNK2001

Comment: what is the exact compilation line + error?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom edited the question to include the error

Answer (score 2):

MSVC uses underscores at the beginning of symbol names, and apparently uses `PUBLIC` to export a symbol (otherwise labels are internal, like `static` variables in C).  Try

```
.data
PUBLIC _foo
_foo DWORD 0
```

This is essentially what MSVC itself does, see https://godbolt.org/z/Phb4Pv

Comment: Note that 64-bit code on Windows doesn't use a leading `_` on asm symbol names, so in that case you *would* want `public foo`.  This answer is correct for 32-bit code.  (Although with a zero initializer you could put it in the BSS instead of .data).